# Where to start_session

Tags: php, session

im following the book

> Php for absolute beginner

and through the book he implements a mvc pattern where he separete files, i know how mvc pattern works, the thing is that sometimes the way things work change a lot and im a beginner with php, im trying to develop a condominium app, and i want to save the session for the user that register for the first time and log in just for testing propose, but i never get the name related to the session, here is what i did:

**index.php**

```
<?php
//check for errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display errors",1);

include_once "Models/PageData.php";
$pageData = new PageData();
$pageData->title = "OSeuCondómiono - Gere tudo apartir de uma única plataforma";
$pageData->bootstrap = "<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'rel='stylesheet'>";
$pageData->jquery = "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>";
$pageData->bootstrapScript = "<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>"; 
$pageData->googleApiFont = "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans|Oswald|Roboto'>";
$pageData->addCss("Css/style.css");
$pageData->content = include_once "Views/home.php";

$formButton = isset($_GET['page']);
if($formButton)
{
    $pageUrl = $_GET['page'];
    $pageData->content = include_once "Controllers/$pageUrl.php";
}
$page = include_once "Views/layout.php";
echo $page;
```

?>

**layout.php(skeleton)**

```
<?php
return
 "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<title>$pageData->title</title>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    $pageData->bootstrap
    $pageData->jquery
    $pageData->bootstrapScript
    $pageData->googleApiFont
    $pageData->css
</head>
<body>
    $pageData->content
</body>
</html>";
?>
```

as i readed in some places, the session_start() function should be before the  i already tryed to place it all the way i never get the session name correctly, here is the place where i set the session

**home**

```
<?php
return "
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row imageBlock sky'>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios.png'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios2.png'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios3.png'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios4.png'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <h3 class='text-center' id='titulo'>OSeuCondomínio</h3>"
            ."<p>".isset($_SESSION['nome'])?$_SESSION['nome']:''."</p>.
        </div>
        <div class='row enter-block myBox'>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Quer Gerir o
                condomínio, tendo a possibilidade de marcar reuniões, registar
                intervenções e guardar ficheiros?</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Quer ter acesso
                a tudo o que se passa no seu apartamento sem saír do lugar?</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Quer efetuar o
                pagamento das quotas através da plataforma?</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Pretende
                conversar aqui com os moradores?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row main-text'>
            <header>
                <h5 class='text-center main-text-content'>Se respondeu que sim
                a pelo menos uma das questões esta é a plataforma ideal para
                si !!</h5>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class='row responsive nowrap'>
            <a href='index.php?page=LoginFormCont'><button class='btn btn-lg center-block EntreJa'>Entre Já</span></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>";
    ?><?php
return "
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row imageBlock sky'>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios.png'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios2.png'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios3.png'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive house' src=
            'Imagens/pr%C3%A9dios4.png'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <h3 class='text-center' id='titulo'>OSeuCondomínio</h3>"
            ."<p>".isset($_SESSION['nome'])?$_SESSION['nome']:''."</p>.
        </div>
        <div class='row enter-block myBox'>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Quer Gerir o
                condomínio, tendo a possibilidade de marcar reuniões, registar
                intervenções e guardar ficheiros?</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Quer ter acesso
                a tudo o que se passa no seu apartamento sem saír do lugar?</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Quer efetuar o
                pagamento das quotas através da plataforma?</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'>
                <p class='okText'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Pretende
                conversar aqui com os moradores?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row main-text'>
            <header>
                <h5 class='text-center main-text-content'>Se respondeu que sim
                a pelo menos uma das questões esta é a plataforma ideal para
                si !!</h5>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class='row responsive nowrap'>
            <a href='index.php?page=LoginFormCont'><button class='btn btn-lg center-block EntreJa'>Entre Já</span></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>";
    ?>
```

ps: sorry for the long post, i hope i was clear about my doubt :/

Comment: Normally, I would put the session_start at the beginning below my error_reporting settings. However, I could be blind, but I am not seeing where the $_SESSION variables are being set.

Comment: in the middle of that big html in the last code that i put, there i compare if the session is already set, if not it writes empty, if yes it should write the name.

Comment: i wanted to use the session_start() in my skeleton in the layout code before the doctype how can i do it without causing me errors, every thing that i tryed didnt worked because i have the return statement it confused me a bit